# Scala 2.10 macros compared to what is available in Java

Tags: java, scala, macros, scala-2.10

I don't know this field so much.

Can someone explain what is possible in Scala 2.10 with macros, compared to what is possible in Java with compilation preprocessors, and tools like CGLIB, ASM, Byteman...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[Update]**: I've Tried to incorporate an example using [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/). It's difficult to sum up a lot of this stuff for a Java (non-Scala) audience.

Macros in Scala 2.10 bring full-blown meta-programming to the language proper, as a first-class citizen.

```
// we often do this:
log("(myList++otherList).size: " + (myList++otherList).size)
// just to log the string:  
// "(myList++otherList).size: 42"

// Imagine log, if implemented as a macro:
log((myList++otherList).size)
// could potentially log both the EXPRESSION AND IT'S VALUE:
// "(myList++otherList).size: 42"
```

Could features like this *generally* be achieved via either textual preprocessing or 
byte-code manipulation in a safe and clean way?

Meta-programming comes down to code-generation at some stage, and unqualified, it is an umbrella term for a variety of techniques - in the interest of 'not having to write a bit of code yourself' - if one were to enumerate some of these techniques in some rough order of *stage* - from pre-compiled raw source to executing code, the list might look like:

- textual source preprocessors (C)
- template systems (C++) (many might argue that the above are too 
  primitive to be considered)
- reflection 'naturally available' in some dynamic languages (Ruby)
- run-time reflection in statically typed languages (Java), which
  renders some dynamism to the language at the cost of type safety
- byte code manipulation

*(Notice I've omitted macro systems that **run at compile time**, more about them in the next paragraph.)*

First, consider that all the above techniques essentially generate *code* - be it the generation/manipulation of plain textual source code or the generation/manipulation of byte code at run time.

What about macro systems?   Macros that run at compile time and *operate not on textual source code nor on compiled byte code, but at a far more valuable stage* - they work on the *AST* of the program during compilation and the information available there and the integration with the compilation process renders them some powerful advantages. They are available both in dynamic languages (such as Lisp and Dylan) and in statically typed languages (*Template Haskell* and *Scala 2.10's self-cleaning Macros)*.

Regarding Macros in Scala 2.10, off the top of my head, 
I'd say the most important advantage would be:

**Type Safety**: Compilation preprocessors and byte-code manipulation cannot
take advantage of the type system. With macros - particularly **compile-time** macros -the kind that Scala 2.10 will have, the macro language is Scala itself with access to the compiler's API. Any kind of static analysis / checking of source code with full type information that is usually possibly only at compile time will be available to macros.

**(Safe) Syntax Extension**: Macros make it possible to adapt language constructs to better implement DSLs.  A good example is [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/), a database library that lets you express SQL queries as type-safe Scala code:

Consider first, plain Scala list processing - no talk of databases or macros yet:

```
val coffees : List[Coffee] = // gotten from somewhere

// get from this list a list of (name, price) pairs also filtering on some condition
for {
  c <- coffees if c.supID == 101
  //                      ^ comparing an Int to an Int - normal stuff.
} yield (c.name, c.price)

// For Java programmers, the above is Scala's syntactic sugar for
coffees.filter(c => c.supId == 101).map(c => (c.name, c.price))
```

Slick, even the *non-macro* version, lets you treat database tables as if they were
Scala collections: This is how the *non-macro* version (Slick calls it the *lifted embedding* API) achieves the same, were `Coffee`s an SQL table instead:

```
// WITHOUT MACROS (using enough of Scala's other features):
// Generates a query "SELECT NAME,PRICE FROM COFFEES IF SUP_ID = 101" 
for {
  c <- Coffees if c.supID === 101
  //                      ^ comparing Rep[Int] to Rep[Int]!
  // The above is Scala-shorthand for
  //     c <- Coffees if c.supID.===(Const[Int](101))
} yield (c.name, c.price)
```

Close enough! But here the `===` method is used to imitate `==` which cannot be used for the obvious reason that you can't compare the *representation of an SQL column* with an actual `Int`.

This is solved in the macro version, if you have Scala 2.10 handy:

```
// WITH MACROS:
// Generates a query "SELECT NAME,PRICE FROM COFFEES IF SUP_ID = 101" 
for {
  c <- coffees if c.supID == 101
  //                      ^ comparing Int to Int!
} yield (c.name, c.price)
```

So here macros are leveraged to provide the *same syntax* both for SQL as well as a plain Scala collection. It is the combination of type safety and macro hygiene *in addition* to the already present expressiveness and compositionality available in Scala that makes Macros attractive.

Also, consider this example from the link contributed by the other answer:

```
def assert(cond: Boolean, msg: Any) = macro impl

def impl(c: Context)(cond: c.Expr[Boolean], msg: c.Expr[Any]) =
  if (assertionsEnabled)
    // if (!cond) raise(msg)
    If(Select(cond.tree, newTermName("$unary_bang")),
        Apply(Ident(newTermName("raise")), List(msg.tree)),
        Literal(Constant(())))
  else
    Literal(Constant(())
```

So that defines a macro `assert`, whose usage will resemble a method call:

```
import assert
assert(2 + 2 == 4, "weird arithmetic")
```

Only, because `assert` is a macro and not a method, the boolean expression `2 + 2 == 4` **will be evaluated only if assertions were enabled**. *Note that there exists a shorthand to help with expressing AST's, but this example is hopefully clearer this way*.

Last but not least - Scala 2.10 macros will be a part of Scala proper - **Integrated into the standard distribution**  - 
as opposed to provided by some third-party library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using MyBatis and there is a maven plugin code generator that creates typesafe dao's configuration (with most common usecases) for all our tables. What is the advantage of Slick compared to using a code generator?

Comment: With type macros ... that you wouldn't need one. Type in the connection string to your database and the compiler fetches all the types it needs directly from there. And if the database changes, the IDE will start yelling at you a few microseconds later, because there is no intermediate step.

Comment: So you mean the main advantage is fail-fast behavior

Comment: @SebastienLorber thanks for the info about MyBatis - do you have a link (about the typesafe maven plugin)?  I'm a little out of touch with Java ORMs, and I blame it all entirely on how great life is with Scala (and Slick).

Comment: @SebastienLorber - one advantage of Slick is that as it allows you to express queries as plain scala, queries are *composable* - you could build complex queries from individual ones that are all statically type checked. It's just too good, but you'll have had to have drunk the Scala cool-aid first...

Comment: @Faiz thanks for your answer. MyBatis Generator is not as nice. It generates an interface and can automatically create the implementation through a generated configuration. But you have to add extra stuff in the configuration, or edit the generated one, and this is not typesafe and can lead to runtime exceptions. With Slick do you have to provide a database schema url during compilation or something?

Comment: @SebastienLorber Note that Slick with Scala 2.10 macros is not yet stable.  As of now, you define your Schema in Scala code (which is not as painful as Java or Xml). So yes, the **stable** Slick as of now needs you to define your tables once - but luckily in one place only. However, there is no reason why this cannot be done with macros and I'm guessing someone will do it once Slick for the Scala 2.10 stabilizes ;-) -

Comment: automated schema generation is round the corner - http://scalamacros.org/usecases/type-providers.html As for Slick, the query DSL is the main focus.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the points mentioned by Faiz, Scala macros are [hygienic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro): they won't suffer from accidental capturing of identifiers. In particular, Scala macros are [self cleaning](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O879Iz-567FzVb8kw6N5OBpei9dnbW0ZaT7-XNSa6Cs/edit): hygiene is achieved by reification where reification itself is a macro. For deeper insight on how this works see [Scala Macros, a Technical Report](http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-07-09-MetaSlides.pdf).